# New directory not being created until I reopen VIM

Tags: c

I have written this C file that will duplicate a given text file into a directory that the user provides.

If the directory already exists, it adds "Archive" to the end of the name, and creates the new directory and then copies the file into it.

If the directory exists, my file is properly adding "Archive" to the name, but it isn't creating the new directory. It seems to just hang. If I type `vim Duplicator.c` in my terminal to reopen the file, then it seems to get created and the file continues and then finishes.

I'm not sure where i'm going wrong. I'm still relatively new to C Programming.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

// main function
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {    
    // variables containing command args (file name/output folder)
    char *file_name = argv[1];
    char *output_folder = argv[2];

    DIR *dir = opendir(output_folder);


    if (dir) {
        char new_dir [80];
        sprintf(new_dir, "%s%s", output_folder, "Archive");
        int rename_dir = rename(output_folder, new_dir);
        closedir(dir);      
    }



    // create directory specified by user
    int create_dir = mkdir(output_folder, 0700);

    // open text file specified by user
    FILE *text_file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    // append file name to directory specified by user
    char out[80];
    sprintf(out, "%s/%s", output_folder, file_name);

    // create new file (same name as original file, just in the new directory)
    FILE *new_file = fopen(out, "w");   
    char line [80]; 

    // write each line of original file into new file
    while (fgets(line, 80, text_file) != NULL){
        fputs(line, new_file);

    }       

    // close both files
    int close1 = fclose(text_file);
    int close2 = fclose(new_file);


}
```

Comment: C programs aren't usually called "scripts". Scripts are programs that are run by interpreters, not programs that are compiled into binary executables.

Comment: @Barmar I see, thanks. Do you have any idea why this happens? It renames the directory and then hangs until I reopen the program in VIM.

Comment: Why do you have an empty `else{}` block? And why do you call `opendir(new_dir)`?

Comment: I can't think of any way that opening the source file in `vim` could have any effect on the result of running the program.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, that shouldn't have been there. Had the code copied from an earlier point. The problem still exists.

Comment: You say the program seems to hang. Have you tried running it in a debugger to see where it's getting stuck?

Comment: This shouldn't be happening.  Run the program under `strace -tt -f` and post the last 20 or so lines of the output, *unedited*.

Comment: Can you show us how you run this program (sample arguments, etc)?  Can you show modify the program to print out the names as it works with them?  Are you sure your buffers are long enough — especially the file name and directory name buffers.  What should happen if the Archive directory already exists?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm compiling with `gcc -o Duplicator Duplicator.c` and running it with `./Duplicator helloworld.txt output_folder`. I'm currently not doing anything if the Archive directory already exists. That's what i'm going to tackle after this.

Comment: OK; you assign various system call results to variables but you don't check the results.  Have you added checks? You need to make sure all system calls that you think should succeed actually do succeed. (`rename`, `mkdir`, `fopen` a couple of times).  When things are failing, it is crucial to put those explicit checks in place.  Create yourself a function to make it easy (see [How to use semaphores properly in Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24353133/how-to-use-semaphores-properly-in-unix-c/24358882?s=22|0.3533#24358882) for an example `err_syserr()` implementation — it's what I use).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I appreciate the help. Do you think you could delve more into what you mean about checks? I don't have much experience with C.

Comment: You have: `int rename_dir = rename(output_folder, new_dir);` —— You need to add: `if (rename_dir != 0) err_syserr("Failed to rename '%s' to '%s'\n", output_folder, new_dir);` or do away with the variable and simply write: `if (rename(output_folder, new_dir) != 0) err_syserr("Failed to rename '%s' to '%s'\n", output_folder, new_dir);`.  And the advantage of the error reporting function is that you only add one line of code, not a printing operation and an exit and a close brace (and maybe a line for the open brace).  It's more succinct, and therefore more likely to be done properly.

Comment: And note that the error reports should include the names that caused the trouble when possible.  In this code, that's easy; sometimes in library code, it isn't, but there are other issues then, too, such as "should the library report an error at all — by printing" and "should the library exit unilaterally". The answer to both questions may be "No".  But that's a future issue for you. Make sure your error messages are as informative as possible — remembering the audience who'll be using the program (that's mainly "you" and maybe a TA or professor at the moment — that too will change with time).

Comment: And especially when file names and/or other data are provided by the user, which may be mistyped, mistaken or even malicious, it is essential to check the return value from functions which indicate their success or failure. Never trust users to enter what you expect them to.

Comment: Also, you might want to think about whether to check that you can open the file before dinking with renaming and creating directories.  That's most definitely a refinement rather than a necessary change, though.

Comment: There's a slightly better, but still close to minimalist, implementation of `err_syserr()` in [Sorting records from a binary file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682323/sorting-records-from-a-binary-file-in-c/39683333#39683333).  I have a library which provides more sophisticated support code — automatic time stamping, PID, etc — which I use in most of my code. See `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` at https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq.